# Возвращение двух значений из функции

Tags: javascript

Как вернуть две строковые переменные из функции? Проблема в том, что в `console.log` выводится только одна переменная:

```js
let h = 'hello';
let w = 'world';

function MyTest() {
  return h, w;
}
console.log(MyTest(h, w))
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: let h = 'hello';
       let w = 'world';

       function MyTest(){
         return h,w;
       }  

       console.log(MyTest(h,w))

Comment: возвращай массив в котором элементами будут эти переменные

Comment: А без массива нельзя?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let h = 'hello';
let w = 'world';

function MyTest(a, b) {
  return {a, b};
}

console.log(MyTest(h, w))
```

---

> Мне нужно без массива

```js
let h = 'hello';
let w = 'world';

function MyTest(a, b) {
  return `${a}, ${b}`;
}

console.log(MyTest(h, w))
```

Comment: Мне нужно без массива, так нельзя?

Comment: @BlackScreen можно

Comment: @BlackScreen в первом варианте ответа возвращается объект, а не массив. Вообще, с возвращением нескольких значений вариантов не густо: объект, массив, сериализованные данные (как во втором примере)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я просто только недавно тут зарегистрировался, и не все понимаю)

Comment: @BlackScreen Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.